# How to give AWS api gateway stage variable in resource integration uri

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have created a stage variable in each stage of AWS API gateway. This variable name contains hostname of backend api.

Now i am trying to update resource integration URI using aws update-integration command with stage variable.

My update-integration command is as follow:

```
aws apigateway update-integration --rest-api-id  apiId --resource-id resId --http-method GET --patch-operations op='replace',path='/uri',value='http://${stageVariables.variablename}'
```

Upon executing above command i am getting:

`-bash: http://${stageVariables.variablename}: bad substitution`

error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the issue i changed my approach of creating uri
now my uri is in http://hostname**$\{stageVariables.variablename\}** format.
and stage variable name contains relative uri path of the form "Api_Stage_Name\endpoint_uri"

one important change was i escaped curly braces using \.